# My Jquery only works when the page is refreshed?

Tags: jquery

This code only works when I refresh, however I want this to work live

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'conditionally_hid' );
function conditionally_hid(){
  jQuery(function($){
    $("#customer_login").each(function() {
      if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
        // handle non visible state
        $('.steps').insertAfter( $('.actions') );  
      } else {
        // handle visible state
        $('.actions').insertAfter( $('.steps') ); 
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this `$("#customer_login").each`. Identifier must be unique.

If each time you insert a "customer_login" block, you want insert something after. You can add an event listener on "DOMNodeInserted" event.

Comment: Or just use a class `$('.customer_login');`